# What is the meaning of Manifest-Version, Bundle-ManifestVersion, Bundle-Version?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rcp, e4

What impact will be happen if I change the Bundle-Version which present in Manifest.MF file?

Also I could not understand why we used Bundle-Version, Manifest-Version, Bundle-ManifestVersion into Manifest.MF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Manifest-Version` is the version of the Java [manifest specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) that this manifest uses - normally always 1.0. You won't normally change this.

`Bundle-ManifestVersion` is the version of the OSGi [manifest specification](https://www.osgi.org/bundle-headers-reference/) that this manifest uses. Again you won't normally change this.

`Bundle-Version` is the version of the plugin in the form 'major.minor.micro.qualifier'. 'qualifier' is usually some sort of build id. You will normally increment one of 'major', 'minor' or 'micro' each time you change the plugin.

OSGi uses the term 'Bundle' for what Eclipse calls a 'plug-in'.

Answer (score 0):

- [`Bundle-Version`](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.module.html#i2655136) - The **version of the OSGi bundle** (in Eclipse bundles are also called plug-ins): bundles can define dependencies to other bundles in a version range
- [`Manifest-Version`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html) - The version of the **JAR Manifest format** (up to now `1.0`)
- [`Bundle-ManifestVersion`](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.module.html#d0e1971) - The version of the **OSGi Manifest format** which extends the JAR Manifest format (`2` since release 4)